# Backbone Collection + Instagram API

Tags: backbone.js

Hello i have just dived into backbone.

What i am trying to do is make a collection of low_resolution photos from the instagram api feed.

I have model for user that stores all the instagram info like access_token and,

```
 App.Models.Ig_photo({});
```

And a collection ,

```
App.Collections.Ig_photos({function() {
    model: App.Models.Ig_photo,

    url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=",

    sync:function (method, model, options) {
        options.timeout = 10000; // required, or the application won't pick up on 404 responses
        options.dataType = "jsonp";
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
},

    parse: function( response ) {
          return response.data
    } 
}});
```

Now i have some issues here, that my collection doesn't get populated when i do fetch and secondly what i wanted was the accesstoken is saved in my another model called user so how do i access it here?

Also it would be great if someone suggests the approach im taking is correct or not. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the API key to the collection model:

```
App.Collections.Ig_photos.access_token = OtherModel.get("access_token");
```

And use a function for the collection URL:

```
url: function() {
    return "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=" + this.access_token
},
```